# How do I change the height of GIMP to less than 1266 pixels?

Tags: x11, window-management, gimp

I'm having trouble editing in GIMP 2.8.16 because the window is much taller than my monitor, and **can't be resized** to anything smaller.

From `xprop`:

```
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
                user specified location: 0, 0
                program specified minimum size: 564 by 1266
                window gravity: SouthWest
```

I can't resize to anything smaller than that:

```
$ xwininfo -id "$(xdotool selectwindow)" | grep -e Width -e Height
  Width: 564
  Height: 1266
```

My screen:

```
$ xrandr | grep Screen | grep --only-matching 'current [^,]*'
current 1366 x 768
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer by chance: The issue is that in single-window mode the minimum size is determined by the size of the *three parts of the window:*

- the main editing surface,
- the toolbox and
- the dockable dialogues.

The **toolbox** in particular can be resized horizontally to be only **one column wide**, and in that case it makes the window very tall. The solution is simply to **drag the dots on the right side of the toolbox to make it two (or more) columns wide.**

Now the minimum size is more sensible:

```
program specified minimum size: 564 by 688
```

Comment: You could also remove some of the tools you never use (or use via keyboard shortcuts only).

Comment: I don't use GIMP often enough to know *any* of the shortcuts except Ctrl-s, which does something different from every other application ever made. And the things I do use (cropping, sane save) don't even have keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Well, you can assign your own shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

On windows this would be 
In Gimp.
Select Edit

Then Preferences..

Then Default Image.. 
and set your default size..

edit advanced option if need be...
press okay..

Comment: I'm afraid the question (and the fix) is not Windows-related, but rather window-related.

Comment: if I wasn't looking for the display template plug-in, I would not of seen it. I am aware, Thanks.

Comment: Voting to delete because it looks like a bot.

Comment: Wow..your rude..

Comment: I will take note your anti-social stance to a fellow gimp user and go else were.